# How many gems and gem-authors does core Ruby on Rails 3 rely on?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Rails relies on:

- actionmailer = 3.2.0
- actionpack = 3.2.0
- activerecord = 3.2.0
- activeresource = 3.2.0
- activesupport = 3.2.0
- bundler ~> 1.0
- railties = 3.2.0

Each of these gems rely on gems of its own etcetera etcetera. Does anyone have a source or the skills to write a script to figure this out quickly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
gem dependency rails --pipe | gem dependency $1
```

This will traverse the dependency tree for the `rails` gem.

If you have multiple versions of `rails` installed, then do something like:

```
gem dependency rails -v 3.2 --pipe | gem dependency $1
```

**Spoiler**: Rails relies on a *ton* of other gems.

Answer (score 2):

Make a Gemfile with only one gem:

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.0'
```

(You will also have to list the gem source)

Then run:

```
bundle install
```

Then open Gemfile.lock and see what gems are listed. If you open in a text editor which displays line numbers, you can figure out the number without counting, just by looking at the line numbers of the first and last gem listed.